# BCM 4306 not recognized after upgrade on a Dell Latitude D600

Tags: 11.10, wireless, dell, broadcom

This is extremely frustrating to me. I had the wireless card working before I upgraded to 11.10. At first the wireless device was recognized but it told me there was no firmware, so I went ahead and went through the process I did before of installing the b43/b43legacy firmware, and now my wireless device is not even recognized, or showing up anywhere!

```
02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4324] (rev 03)
```

Comment: question edited :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
You may have to physically toggle the wifi card. There should be a button somewhere on your dell for this.  Toggle and restart. I've had to do this two or three times in the past on new installs but once you get it on it should stay on unless you're dual booting with Windows. Then, you'll have to do this every time you use Windows.  Also, make sure wireless is enabled by clicking on the icon in the upper right hand corner and verifying that "enable wireless" is checked.

Problem is, I don't know if you loaded the drivers from system settings>additional drivers or not.  I've always been able to get well working drivers this way.  So, if it wasn't prompting you to install additional drivers automatically, you should first go to it manually through system settings.